# У кукурузы кочан или початок?

Tags: выбор-слов, синонимы

Опять же в Киеве не один раз слышала "кочан" кукурузы, а не "початок". Я всегда считала, что "кочан" (или вилок) это к капусте.  В словаре Ефремовой "початок" (кукурузы) дается как вариант к слову "кочан". Как вы считаете, "початок" и "кочан" в данном случае синонимы?  И в каких единицах считать кукурузу?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Синонимы. Во многих словарях кочан кукурузы даётся с пометой МЕСТН., НАРОДНО -РАЗГ. Вот ответ Грамоты.ру:                             http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?all=x&word=%EA%EE%F7%E0%ED

Так что литературное - початок кукурузы, областническое, диалектное - кочан

Answer (score 3):

Вообще-то, у кукурузы — початок во всех смыслах: и в биологическом (я биолог), и в обиходном. А кочан, он у капусты))))

Comment: Fuchoin Kazuki, а как в биологии определяется, что есть что?
Ну, другими словами, в чем разница между кочном и початком, кроме того, что один у капусты, а другой у кукурузы?  
Я просто напомню, что "кочан" по фасмеру проискходит от основы, обазначающей и стебель, и кочерыжку, но никак не сам вилок (шарик из листьев).

>Кукуру́за (лат. Zea) — род растений семейства Злаки (Poaceae)...    
  
>ПОЧАТОК, у некоторых цветов - простое колосовидное соцветие с толстой мясистой осью,

Answer (score 1):

На все вопросв не отвечу, тут надо быть и биологом, и диалектологом - и черт знает еще кем. Очень кратко.
Для себя - однозначно початок.
Для всех - пусть будет кочан, исходному смыслу (стебель, кочерыжка) не противоречит.
Для филологов - скорее тут можно ставить под сомнение "кочан" в отношении капустного вилка.

Comment: Я имела в виду не столько биологию, сколько лексическую сочетаемость слов. Просто я никогда раньше не слышала "кочан кукурузы", всегда "початок". Вот и задумалась: как правильно? Равноценны ли эти слова в "кукурузном" контексте?

Comment: Никаких проблем для "кочана кукурузы" нет. Остальное - вкусовщина.Тем более, что кукуруза - это злак (как пшеница), у неё именно стебель, не кочепужка.

Answer (score 0):

Есть капуста, а внутри капусты, ее ствол - это качан. В кукурузе тоже самое, ствол кукурузы - это качан, а початок - это маленькая кукурузка молочной свежести, т.е. еще не выросшая до зрелости кукуруза. С украинского на русский початок - это "начало". У нас в Украине эти початки собирают и закрывают в банки. Они очень вкусные, в детстве мы их кушали сырьем. Они очень сладкие и мягкие.

Comment: Вы понимаете, здесь речь идет о принятом в России значении слова "кочан". И оно не совпадает с приведенным Вами. Не о стволе речь, а о всем початке. Или вилке, как у капусты.

Answer (score 0):

Я родился на Украине. Там говорили *кочан кукурузы*.

Comment: Именно *качан*, как у вас было в исходном тексте?